# SQL Database Operational Error - no such table : users

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: users
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.username AS users_username, users.password AS users_password 
FROM users 
WHERE users.username = ?]
```

the above is the error im getting.

```html
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(24), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)
```

this is my User code.

```py
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    reg_form = Registeration()
    if reg_form.validate_on_submit():
        username = reg_form.username.data
        password = reg_form.password.data


        # for checking if someone has taken the username already
        user_object = User.query.filter_by(username=username).all()
        if user_object:
            return "This username has been taken. Try another one.."


        #registering in the database and commiting and etc 
        user = User(username=username, password=password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return 'Registered into the database!'

        return db.create_all()
```

the application code.
I'm unable to figure out.. any help would be greatly appreciated. Btw im trying to make a registration system where the username and the pass get stored in Postgres Database.

Comment: You're `db.create_all()` isn't ever being called. I'd recommend moving that functionality outside of your API code as it will slow your responses down., for example move it into a stand alone script. Also, please *never* store passwords in plaintext!

Comment: [sqlalchemy](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/) comes with a engine called `create_engine`. you can make use of that for what @robinsax said.

Comment: @robinsax can you explain a bit more?